Is a conditional foreign key in SQL Server possible?
Keys can be composite - made up of multiple columns, but both sides of the relationship must have the same number of columns.
For example, given a client table with an ID column and a Staff table with an ID column.
There is also an event table with an ID column and a CorS column which can contain the values C or S.
A value of C in event.CorS says event.ID -> client.id.
A value of S in event.CorS says event.ID -> staff.id.
The software knows about this and writes the SQL accordingly.
How do I define this in the DB Schema to enforce referential integrity in a SQL Server?
This is an old database (almost 25 years and designed by someone with no clue about 3NF) and is part of a much larger DB, so changing the existing schema will prove difficult.  We are attempting to add some Natural Language Query to SQL capability via AI.  We have it working except for these kind of cases.
Suppose we added a CorS column to both Staff and Client.
Would that allow for composite foreign and alternate keys?
Would we be able to just train the AI model to know about the CorS column and make the SQL accordingly?

No............. You could write a trigger to enforce it. Or have 2 separate columns with FKs (clientid & staffid), where 1 is always null

Perhaps you can create two computed persisted columns CASE WHEN Cors = 'C' THEN ID END AS ClientID, CASE WHEN Cors = 'S' THEN ID END AS StaffID and then point them to respective table. This is untested, and i'm not a big fan of FKs nor of this design in general

@siggemannen why not a fan of FKs?

@ken if you tell us the actual problem you are trying to solve we could better assist.

@DaleK The cascade thing never does exactly what one wants and is too finicky (the dreaded multiple cascade paths error), plus, it's hard to actually delete anything and takes forever to design a proper system, better live fast and loose! Oh yeah, it's slow too!

@siggemannen I imagine you up with a lot of hanging records? Its an interesting idea though...

@siggemannen if you think foreign keys are slow... primary keys are already indexed, by definition, but do you also build indexes on your foreign key columns? (It doesn't happen by default.)

@AlwaysLearning i mean the whole verifying thing is slow and not needed when you enforce the integrity yourself. Dale, yeah, it's a tradeoff but usually works out OK!

@siggemannen imho the database is the only one that can actually provide 100% referential integrety, sure doing this in a single point of entry solution offers a great alternative but still no one can stop you from bypassing it. Or am I missing something

One way you could do this is with two separate columns, and a CHECK constraint ensuring only one is valid. For example,
CREATE TABLE Event (
    EventId int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    ClientId int REFERENCES Client (Id),
    StaffId int REFERENCES Staff (Id),
    CHECK (ClientId IS NULL AND StaffId IS NOT NULL OR ClientId IS NOT NULL AND StaffId IS NULL)
);

But this is not really correct database design. You need to redesign this with Polymorphic Association.
Conceptually, a staff or client are both a person, so you need a base table which contains both. Then events can be either client- or staff-related, so you just link it to that base table.
Note the addition of a Type column, which has a CHECK constraint in the base Person table, but is a computed column in the derived tables. It is also part of a secondary key, so that other tables can use a composite foreign key containing it.
CREATE TABLE Person (
    Id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Type char(1) NOT NULL CHECK (Type IN ('C', 'S')),
    Name
    ....... --etc
    INDEX ix UNIQUE (Type, Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Client (
    Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    Type AS 'C',
    FOREIGN KEY (Type, Id) REFERENCES Person (Type, Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Staff (
    Id int PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Person (Id),
    Type AS 'S',
    FOREIGN KEY (Type, Id) REFERENCES Person (Type, Id)
);

CREATE TABLE PersonEvent (
    EventId int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    PersonId int,
    PersonType char(1),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonType, PersonId) REFERENCES Person (Type, Id),
    INDEX ix UNIQUE (EventId, PersonType) INCLUDE (PersonId)
);

If client-related events and staff-related are different in some way then you can also add further derived tables. For example:
CREATE TABLE ClientEvent (
    EventId int PRIMARY KEY,
    PersonType AS 'C',
    SomeClientValue varchar(30),
    FOREIGN KEY (EventId, PersonType) REFERENCES PersonEvent (EventId, PersonType)
);

CREATE TABLE StaffEvent (
    EventId int PRIMARY KEY,
    PersonType AS 'S'
    SomeStaffValue varchar(30),
    FOREIGN KEY (EventId, PersonType) REFERENCES PersonEvent (EventId, PersonType)
);


This is interesting.

As others have answered, what you are asking is not supported by design. Change your design.
You could consider:
CREATE TABLE [Event] (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Cors CHAR(1),
    ObjectType INT,
    ObjectId INT
)

Then act based on object type, but you will lose the referential integrity, enforcement of foreign keys (FK).
Alternatively, create two separate tables i.e. ClientEvent and StaffEvent and use regular FKs
Your issue is not a technical one, it is design.

Personally, if FK integrity is required, I would suggest a single Event table with 2 FKs, one of which will always be null.

Yes Dale, this will work and is always a trade off. And it gets more complicated if additional field with FKs are needed

Foreign keys can be create by two different ways.

the declarative one (CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY... REFERENCES ...)
the procedural one by the bias of triggers

In your, case the firsts one is not possible, but the other can be done. This will need 3 triggers, one for each tables, the ref one and the two children.
But the other way that @Charlieface talk about is the cleanest because it acts at the data model level and use the classical constraint. This modeling technic is weel kown as inheritance and is specially efficient in compacity, and performances
